# Kendo template binding

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to set a kendo template like so:

```
fldInfo.template = '<a href="\\#"> #:kendo.toString(\\\\#:kendo.parseDate(\' \\\\#:data.' + field + '\\\\# \')\\\\#, "MM/dd/yyyy")# </a>';
```

This is defined for a kendo grid.

the `field` value will hold the name of the column in the schema. In this particular instance, i am binding a date field (.net datetime datatype) sent. But because the default datetime conversion from .NET--> JSON --> JS comes in the long date format, i am trying to format it as MM/dd/yyyy.

I read the kendo documentation on templates which says a template symbol `#` should be escaped with 4 `\\\\` but i am not able to get this to work

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try something more like this:

```
fldInfo.template = '<a href="\\#"> #:kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(data[field]), "MM/dd/yyyy")# </a>';
```

If that doesn't work, I'd suggest hard-wiring `field` temporarily as it's most likely looking in the wrong place, due to the javascript scope:

```
fldInfo.template = '<a href="\\#"> #:kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(data["fooField"]), "MM/dd/yyyy")# </a>';
```

Note how the function calls can be nested; your first `#` needs to be escaped as you want it rendered in the output markup. When the parser hits the `#:` you enter a code block, and remain in code until the next `#` at which point you switch back to markup again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Joe!! the first option worked. I was stuck in this mindset of using :# to render the field and never thought of using this way of accessing a JS property ... data["' + field + '"] ...